# Widget into listview or datable in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, datatable

I need to do something like this:

[image]

if I push the red button a row will be deleted

if I push the green button a row will be added between last row with red button and the row with green button

Ingredient's row need 3 text inputs
Direction's row need only one text input

of course at finish I need to read all data of all text inputs

what do you recommend to use

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic form to get all data after the adding field and field add dynamically in form,

You can [refer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2pVgDjDrxQ) this video.

And also you can validate form [refer](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-how-to-validate-fields-dynamically-created-40cafca5c3cb).